# Find a specific digit in a different base

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a decimal number $n$. What's the best way to compute its $k^{th}$ digit in a different base $b$? 
In other words, $n=d_m\cdot b^m+\ldots+d_i\cdot b^i+ \ldots +d_0\cdot b^0$. What's the best way to compute $d_k$ given its position $k$? Do I have to convert the number $n$ in base $b$ using the standard conversion procedure or is there anything more straightforward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k^{th}$ digit is the coefficient of $b^k$, so let $m=\lfloor \frac n{b^k}\rfloor$  then $d_k=m \pmod b$  The first strips off the lower $k$ digits, the second extracts the lowest of what is left.