# The digit at position $n$ of the number $x$ in base $m$

Tags: functions, number-systems

As a solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674294/555969), we can define a function $f_b(x, n)$ which finds the digit in the $n$<sup>th</sup> position of $x$ in base $b$.

$$
f_b(x, n) = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{b^n} \right\rfloor \bmod b
$$

It even works for decimals, for example:

```
e = 2 . 7  1  8  2  8  1  8  2  8 ...
    0  -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 th position
```

$$
f_{10}(e, -8) = 2 \quad \checkmark
$$

However, when using a non-integer base, all the digits are fractional.

$$
f_\pi(e, [0,-1,-2,\dots]) = [2, 1.717, 0.867, 2.319, \dots]
$$

For reference, Wolfram Alpha states that $e$ in base $\pi$ is [actually 2.2021201002111...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%20in%20base%20pi)

Additionally, for negative bases, all the digits of $f$ are negative. Wolfram Alpha states that $e$ in base $-10$ is [3.3223222325590...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%20in%20base%20-10)

Furthermore, the function also screws up if $x_b$ is negative. So I am also looking for a function to have a way of differentiating positive and negative numbers (especially important in negative bases, since for example, 21 in decimal would be -39 in negadecimal).

My question is if there is a function which does this but is also valid even for non-integer and negative bases. I'm sure there would be, but I don't know what we need to modify such that this would happen. In other words, is there a function such that

$$
f_b\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k b^k, n \right) = a_n \qquad b\in\mathbb{R}
$$

?

---

I have since then found a recursive method for non-integer **but not negative bases** :

Start by calculating $A=\lfloor\log_b n\rfloor$, then

$$ U_1 = f_b(n, A) = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{b^A}\right\rfloor $$
$$ U_2 = f_b(n, A-1) = \left\lfloor\frac{n-U_1b^A}{b^{A-1}}\right\rfloor $$
$$ U_3 = f_b(n, A-2) = \left\lfloor\frac{n-U_1b^A-U_2b^{A-1}}{b^{A-2}}\right\rfloor $$

etc. The simple problem with this one is when it deals with a negative base, it returns negative digits.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about the "digits" for such irregular bases. The digits are always nonnegative integers.

For example, the statement "$e$ in base $\pi$ is $2.20212\ldots$" means
$$e = 2 + 2\pi^{-1}+ 0\pi^{-2}+2\pi^{-3}+1\pi^{-4}+2\pi^{-5}+\cdots$$

and the statement "$e$ in base $-10$ is $3.32232\cdots$" means
$$e = 3 + 3(-10)^{-1} + 2(-10)^{-2} + 2(-10)^{-3} + 3(-10)^{-4} + 2(-10)^{-5}+\cdots$$

Comment: @MPW How would one write 15 in base -10? The easiest way is to write -25, right? I know, particularly in irrational bases, that there are loads of different ways to write the same number, but I don't know for a negative base whether for every number there exists a positive number representation...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for starters, try to extract $a$, $b$, $c$ from 
$
\ 
a \pi^2 + b\pi +c
\
$
or, more generally, the digits from
$$
a_1/\pi + a_2/\pi^2 + a_3/\pi^3 + a_4/\pi^4 + a_5/\pi^5 + \cdots
$$
The traditional mod function is not enough, because
$$
a\pi^2 + b\pi +c \pmod {\pi} = a \pi^2 +c \neq c
$$
since $a\pi^2$ isn't an (integer!) multiple of $\pi$.

Edit: Instead of $\!\bmod{\!\! }$, the function $\bmod{\!\! _b}$ that yields
$$
\bmod_b \,\! : \ (A_k b^k + \cdots + A_2 b^2 + A_1 b + A_0) \mapsto A_0
$$
for any nonnegative integers $A_j \leq |b|$, seems to do the trick. But I have no definite formula for now.
$% \mod\!\!\!_b: \ (A_k b^k + \cdots + A_2 b^2 + A_1 b + A_0) \mapsto A_0 $

Comment: Yes, that's what the function would intend to do but for any base $b$ ($a_0 + a_1b + a_2b^2 + \cdots + a_{-1}b^{-1} + a_{-2}b^{-2} + \cdots$), not just $\pi$. Of course I can look at something like $20122.1_\pi$ and say, that's $2\pi^4 + 1\pi^2$ etc. I just want a function that does this for any number $x$.

Comment: Of course I used $\pi$ as an example only. I think it would be enough to use, (instead of mod function) the function $\!\mod\!\!\!_b$ that yields
$$
\mod\!\!\!_b: \ (A_k b^k + \cdots + A_2 b^2 + A_1 b + A_0) \mapsto A_0
$$
where $A_j$ are integers. However, I don't know for now how to define it as a formula.